# Django add hard-coded href links to an admin model's form view page

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

In Django's admin panel, how do I add hard-coded links to a Django model's form page (/add/ page). These are links to documentation that will never change. I want these links to appear every time on the form as a reference for the user to figure out what values to input into the fields.

Do I need: Custom field? Built-in field already? Modify the admin templates somehow? Add a helper function somewhere?

I'm not referring to the "change list" view; I am referring to the `/change/` or `/add/` page view when you go and add or edit an object within a model.

[image: add links in Django admin model form]

models.py

```
class DateRange(models.Model):

    date_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adwords_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bingads_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date_name
```

forms.py

```
class DateRangeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DateRange
        fields = '__all__'
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(DateRange)
class DateRangeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DateRangeAdminForm
    list_display = ['date_name', 'adwords_name', 'bingads_name']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending `change_form.html` could work -- it'll add links at the top.

Create this file in your namespaced templates directory, referred to here as "templates-dir"

`templates-dir/admin/myapp/daterange/change_form.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block object-tools %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://link1.com">Adwords documentation</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://link2.com">Bing ads documentation</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock object-tools %}
```

Relevant docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory

Comment: I have so much to learn. Thank you for your time and effort. Your advice worked. Can I ask you, my localhost link to this page is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/scorecards/daterange/add/`. Is  the reason for all the namespacing to get to the change_form.html because the paths need to match the admin?

Comment: My understanding is that admin templates can be namespaced by app and model so that you can override admin templates for specific models/apps without interfering with others (I wouldn't say the URLs are the "reason", even though they align). For example, if you wanted those links to appear for every model in `myapp`, you could move the file to `templates-dir/admin/myapp/change_form.html`.

Answer (score 0):

If we stick to the screen capture from op, here is what can be done:

```
class AdminExample(admin.ModelAdmin):
  readonly_fields = ('show_url',)
  fields = (......, "show_url",)

  def show_url(self, instance):
    url = reverse('help_link')
    response = format_html('<a href="{0}">{1}</a>', url, 'help_link')
    return response
```

Then don't forget to add in urls.py and views.py for the link to work.

Here is the result:

[image]